# Synchronise access to singleton object initialisation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core, eventstoredb

I'm accessing an [EventStore](https://eventstore.org/docs/dotnet-api/) from a dotnet core web application. There is a single connection shared by all threads. The connection is opened on first access and I need to ensure only one thread opens the connection. Previously I would have used a `lock` but then I can't `await` the method to open the connection.

I found the [following snippet](http://applications.lt/awaiting-in-csharp-lock-block/) of code that looks like it should do the trick:

```
public class AsyncLock : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public async Task<AsyncLock> LockAsync()
    {
        await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}
```

And use it in my code:

```
private static readonly AsyncLock _mutex = new AsyncLock();
private volatile bool _isConnected = false;
private async Task EstablishConnected()
{
    if (!_isConnected)
    {
        using (await _mutex.LockAsync())
        {
            if (!_isConnected)
            {
                await _connection.ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                _isConnected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a reasonable approach to synchronising access to initialise/open the connection to the EventStore?

Comment: Would https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/15/asynclazyt/ help?

Comment: I have found Stephen Cleary's AsyncEx library https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx that is a drop in replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is a useful [nuget library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/5.0.0-pre-05) and associated [Github repo](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) from [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/) that is a drop in replacement for the `AsyncLock` class above.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is reasonable.  However, if you're looking for asynchronous ways of managing initialization, take a look at some of the objects available in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading package, like `AsyncLazy`.  I don't think the package is available for .NET core, but the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading) is on github and under the MIT license.

Using AsyncLazy, you could do something like this:

```
public class MyEventStoreConsumer
{
    private static readonly Func<Task<IEventStoreConnection>> getConnection;

    static MyEventStoreConsumer()
    {
        var eventStore = EventStoreConnection.Create(...);
        var connection = new AsyncLazy<IEventStoreConnection>(async () =>
        {
            await eventStore.ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return eventStore;
        });
        getConnection = () => connection.GetValueAsync();
    }
}
```